# Webpack - web app needs a reload on releases

Tags: nginx, webpack

I work with webpack to generate my react client web application. I'm doing it all: extract vendors, uglify, minify ....

Every time I release a new version of the application, the browser fails to load it. It can be an error loading a file or other reasons but it happens after a rebuild for sure.

Any ideas how this can be investigated?

Comment: Does it happen *while* the deployment is happening, just afterwards, for some period of time afterwards, or to everyone who uses the app after the new code is deployed, regardless of how long it's been since they have used the app?

Comment: @SeanVieira it happens after the deployment finishes.

Comment: My best guess would be that you're copying the files over the existing files and when you first hit the server it somehow hasn't picked them up.  You can check by `curl`-ing the resources while doing a release.  If they start missing at some point, whatever you are doing in your release process is not atomic.  For example, if using symlinks, you want something [like this](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2005-08-22-how-to-change-symlinks-atomically.html) (which isn't at all intuitive).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using simlinks ... but weirdly enough this issue didn't happen for some time so I'll monitor that to see what happens.